# Postfix Dovecot Pi server cant connect to email client even though it can send and receive emails

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird, domain, postfix

I followed the sam hobbs tutorial for setting up a postfix dovecot email server on a pi and with quite a bit of research and trouble i got my pi server running (can send and receive emails), but i tried to connect to thunderbird and then evolution to no avail. I'm a noob who has always relied on the kindness of strangers. Thanks in advance.

BLAM! (code dump) main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Raspbian)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom

# SMTP from your server to others
smtp_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtp_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# SMTP from other servers to yours
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_cert_file= /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file= /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = host.domain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = easydns.com
mydestination = $myhostname, domain.com, mail, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = [mailout.easydns.com]
mynetworks = 192.xxx.x.xx, 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = 192.xxx.x.xx, 127.0.0.1
inet_protocols = ipv4

home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command =

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject_unauth_destination

smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
        reject_unknown_helo_hostname,
        check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/helo_access

# Added for smtp auth
# enable SASL authentication
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
# disallow methods that allow anonymous authentication.
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
# where to find sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
# Enable STARTTLS encryption
smtp_use_tls = yes
# where to find CA certificates
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
```

ANNNNNND master.cf

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
#
# ====================================================================
#Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

EDIT
dovecot -n:

```
$ sudo doveconf -n
# 2.3.4.1 (f79e8e7e4): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.4 ()
doveconf: Warning: NOTE: You can get a new clean config file with: doveconf -Pn > dovecot-new.conf
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf:77: ssl_protocols has been replaced by ssl_min_protocol
# OS: Linux 4.19.97-v7+ armv7l Debian 10.3 
# Hostname: mail.domain.com
auth_mechanisms = plain login
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox {
    special_use = \Drafts
    name = Drafts
  }
  mailbox {
    special_use = \Junk
    name = Junk
  }
  mailbox {
    special_use = \Sent
    name = Sent
  }
  mailbox {
    special_use = \Sent
    name = Sent Messages
  }
  mailbox {
    special_use = \Trash
    name = Trash
  }
  prefix = 
  name = inbox
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = " imap"
service replication-notify-fifo {
  name = aggregator
}
service anvil-auth-penalty {
  name = anvil
}
service auth-worker {
  name = auth-worker
}
service {
  unix_listener {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
    path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
  }
  name = auth
}
service config {
  name = config
}
service dict-async {
  name = dict-async
}
service dict {
  name = dict
}
service login/proxy-notify {
  name = director
}
service dns-client {
  name = dns_client
}
service doveadm-server {
  name = doveadm
}
service imap-hibernate {
  name = imap-hibernate
}
service {
  inet_listener {
    port = 143
    name = imap
  }
  inet_listener {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
    name = imaps
  }
  name = imap-login
}
service imap-urlauth {
  name = imap-urlauth-login
}
service imap-urlauth-worker {
  name = imap-urlauth-worker
}
service token-login/imap-urlauth {
  name = imap-urlauth
}
service imap-master {
  name = imap
}
service indexer-worker {
  name = indexer-worker
}
service indexer {
  name = indexer
}
service ipc {
  name = ipc
}
service lmtp {
  name = lmtp
}
service log-errors {
  name = log
}
service old-stats-mail {
  name = old-stats
}
service pop3 {
  name = pop3-login
}
service login/pop3 {
  name = pop3
}
service replicator-doveadm {
  name = replicator
}
service stats-reader {
  name = stats
}
service submission {
  name = submission-login
}
service login/submission {
  name = submission
}
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
submission_max_mail_size = 0
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
protocol lmtp {
  service replication-notify-fifo {
    name = aggregator
  }
  service anvil-auth-penalty {
    name = anvil
  }
  service auth-worker {
    name = auth-worker
  }
  service auth-client {
    name = auth
  }
  service config {
    name = config
  }
  service dict-async {
    name = dict-async
  }
  service dict {
    name = dict
  }
  service login/proxy-notify {
    name = director
  }
  service dns-client {
    name = dns_client
  }
  service doveadm-server {
    name = doveadm
  }
  service imap-hibernate {
    name = imap-hibernate
  }
  service imap {
    name = imap-login
  }
  service imap-urlauth {
    name = imap-urlauth-login
  }
  service imap-urlauth-worker {
    name = imap-urlauth-worker
  }
  service token-login/imap-urlauth {
    name = imap-urlauth
  }
  service imap-master {
    name = imap
  }
  service indexer-worker {
    name = indexer-worker
  }
  service indexer {
    name = indexer
  }
  service ipc {
    name = ipc
  }
  service lmtp {
    name = lmtp
  }
  service log-errors {
    name = log
  }
  service old-stats-mail {
    name = old-stats
  }
  service pop3 {
    name = pop3-login
  }
  service login/pop3 {
    name = pop3
  }
  service replicator-doveadm {
    name = replicator
  }
  service stats-reader {
    name = stats
  }
  service submission {
    name = submission-login
  }
  service login/submission {
    name = submission
  }
  submission_max_mail_size = 0
}
protocol !indexer-worker {
  service replication-notify-fifo {
    name = aggregator
  }
  service anvil-auth-penalty {
    name = anvil
  }
  service auth-worker {
    name = auth-worker
  }
  service auth-client {
    name = auth
  }
  service config {
    name = config
  }
  service dict-async {
    name = dict-async
  }
  service dict {
    name = dict
  }
  service login/proxy-notify {
    name = director
  }
  service dns-client {
    name = dns_client
  }
  service doveadm-server {
    name = doveadm
  }
  service imap-hibernate {
    name = imap-hibernate
  }
  service imap {
    name = imap-login
  }
  service imap-urlauth {
    name = imap-urlauth-login
  }
  service imap-urlauth-worker {
    name = imap-urlauth-worker
  }
  service token-login/imap-urlauth {
    name = imap-urlauth
  }
  service imap-master {
    name = imap
  }
  service indexer-worker {
    name = indexer-worker
  }
  service indexer {
    name = indexer
  }
  service ipc {
    name = ipc
  }
  service lmtp {
    name = lmtp
  }
  service log-errors {
    name = log
  }
  service old-stats-mail {
    name = old-stats
  }
  service pop3 {
    name = pop3-login
  }
  service login/pop3 {
    name = pop3
  }
  service replicator-doveadm {
    name = replicator
  }
  service stats-reader {
    name = stats
  }
  service submission {
    name = submission-login
  }
  service login/submission {
    name = submission
  }
  submission_max_mail_size = 0
}
protocol lda {
  service replication-notify-fifo {
    name = aggregator
  }
  service anvil-auth-penalty {
    name = anvil
  }
  service auth-worker {
    name = auth-worker
  }
  service auth-client {
    name = auth
  }
  service config {
    name = config
  }
  service dict-async {
    name = dict-async
  }
  service dict {
    name = dict
  }
  service login/proxy-notify {
    name = director
  }
  service dns-client {
    name = dns_client
  }
  service doveadm-server {
    name = doveadm
  }
  service imap-hibernate {
    name = imap-hibernate
  }
  service imap {
    name = imap-login
  }
  service imap-urlauth {
    name = imap-urlauth-login
  }
  service imap-urlauth-worker {
    name = imap-urlauth-worker
  }
  service token-login/imap-urlauth {
    name = imap-urlauth
  }
  service imap-master {
    name = imap
  }
  service indexer-worker {
    name = indexer-worker
  }
  service indexer {
    name = indexer
  }
  service ipc {
    name = ipc
  }
  service lmtp {
    name = lmtp
  }
  service log-errors {
    name = log
  }
  service old-stats-mail {
    name = old-stats
  }
  service pop3 {
    name = pop3-login
  }
  service login/pop3 {
    name = pop3
  }
  service replicator-doveadm {
    name = replicator
  }
  service stats-reader {
    name = stats
  }
  service submission {
    name = submission-login
  }
  service login/submission {
    name = submission
  }
  submission_max_mail_size = 0
}
protocol imap {
  service replication-notify-fifo {
    name = aggregator
  }
  service anvil-auth-penalty {
    name = anvil
  }
  service auth-worker {
    name = auth-worker
  }
  service auth-client {
    name = auth
  }
  service config {
    name = config
  }
  service dict-async {
    name = dict-async
  }
  service dict {
    name = dict
  }
  service login/proxy-notify {
    name = director
  }
  service dns-client {
    name = dns_client
  }
  service doveadm-server {
    name = doveadm
  }
  service imap-hibernate {
    name = imap-hibernate
  }
  service imap {
    name = imap-login
  }
  service imap-urlauth {
    name = imap-urlauth-login
  }
  service imap-urlauth-worker {
    name = imap-urlauth-worker
  }
  service token-login/imap-urlauth {
    name = imap-urlauth
  }
  service imap-master {
    name = imap
  }
  service indexer-worker {
    name = indexer-worker
  }
  service indexer {
    name = indexer
  }
  service ipc {
    name = ipc
  }
  service lmtp {
    name = lmtp
  }
  service log-errors {
    name = log
  }
  service old-stats-mail {
    name = old-stats
  }
  service pop3 {
    name = pop3-login
  }
  service login/pop3 {
    name = pop3
  }
  service replicator-doveadm {
    name = replicator
  }
  service stats-reader {
    name = stats
  }
  service submission {
    name = submission-login
  }
  service login/submission {
    name = submission
  }
  submission_max_mail_size = 0
```

I have domain and thru easydns and ddclient a dynamic ip. Dunno if that helps.

Lemme know if you need anything else. I am confident the internet will answer my prayers.

Comment: Where's your Dovecot configuration (doveconf -n)? What are the actual error messages from Thunderbird and Evolution (if any)?

Comment: The error was "could not login at server, probably wrong username password configuration."

Comment: Actually I think I might need a dns server